# How do add to rotation instead of setting it? Java3d

Tags: java, rotation, transform, angle, java-3d

Basically I have this class:

```
package Actions;

import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.vecmath.AxisAngle4f;

public class Rotate {
    public Rotate(Transform3D Trans, TransformGroup group, float SpinVar, float Speed, String Axis) {
        switch(Axis.toLowerCase()) {
        case "x":
            Trans.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(Speed,0f,0f,SpinVar));
            break;
        
        case "y":
            Trans.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(0f,Speed,0f,SpinVar));
            break;
        
        case "z":
            Trans.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(0f,0f,Speed,SpinVar));
            break;
        
        }
        group.setTransform(Trans);
    }
}
```

to rotate a given transform but (as you can expect) since the code is written to set rotation with at least one of the values being `0f` it resets the angle on one of the axis which is not wanted, instead I want a way to be able to add to the rotation value instead of setting it so it makes it easier to read and wont reset the transforms rotational value on any axis :)

Comment: You're *setting* the transform to a fixed value. There are [`add`](https://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.0/javax/media/j3d/Transform3D.html#add(javax.media.j3d.Transform3D)) and [`mul`](https://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.0/javax/media/j3d/Transform3D.html#mul(javax.media.j3d.Transform3D)) operations, which act on the current `Transform3D`

Comment: @QBrute I changed it to `switch(Axis.toLowerCase()) {
  case "x":
   vec = new Vector3f(Speed,0f,0f);
   break;
  
  case "y":
   vec = new Vector3f(0f,Speed,0f);
   break;
  
  case "z":
   vec = new Vector3f(0f,0f,Speed);
   break;
  
  }
  Transform3D Trans2 = new Transform3D();
  Trans2.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(vec.x,vec.y,vec.z,SpinVar));` and now i get
`Exception in thread "GameThread" javax.media.j3d.BadTransformException: TransformGroup: non-affine transform`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations